# Let $G$ be a finite group, $H\le G$ and $N\unlhd G$ such that $\gcd(|H|,[G:N])=1$. Prove that $H\le N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Task I'm trying to solve is:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $H\le G$ and $N\unlhd G$ such that $\gcd(|H|,[G:N])=1$. Prove that $H\le N$.

I have the following proof but I'm really not confident with it:

> Since $\gcd(|H|, [G : N]) = 1$, this implies that $H\cap G/N = \{e\}$. We also know from the 2nd isomorphism theorem that $HN<G$. However, this implies that $H<N$ since otherwise $H\cap G/N = \{e\}$ would not hold.

Am I making sense?

Comment: Why does the subgroup $G \cap H$ contain $N?$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What do you mean by "N E G"?

Comment: N is normal to G, i corrected it. Edit: Thank you.

Comment: @Carlo The intersection of H and G/N should be {e}(i think) since the gcd of their orders is 1. Would this somehow imply that the intersection of G and H is N?

Comment: @Hristmar, the problem is that $H$ and $G / N$ are different objects, so they cannot have an element in common. (One is a subgroup of $G;$ the other is a quotient group of $G,$ so its elements are cosets.) Check my solution for a different approach that takes cues from your solution.

Answer (score 5):

By the Second Isomorphism Theorem, we have that $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order $$|HN| = \frac{|H|\, |N|}{|H \cap N|}.$$ By Lagrange's Theorem, we have that $$|G| = [G : HN] \, |HN| = \frac{[G : HN] \, |H| \, |N|}{|H \cap N|} = \frac{[G : HN] \, |H| \, |G|}{[G : N] \, |H \cap N|}.$$ Cancelling the factor of $|G|$ from both sides and clearing denominators gives us that $[G : N] \, |H \cap N| = [G : HN] \, |H|.$ By hypothesis that $\gcd(|H|, [G : N]) = 1,$ we must have that $|H|$ divides $|H \cap N|$ so that $|H| \leq |H \cap N|.$ But this implies that $|H| = |H \cap N|.$ We conclude therefore that $|HN| = |N|$ so that $HN = N,$ from which it follows that $H \leq N.$ QED.

Comment: I have no idea how you got the last equality. But that's not even the problem. There is 0% chance this would come intuitively to me when seeing this task. What's the motivation behind this proof? Why consider the order of G? There must be a simpler way around this.

Comment: Observe that $HN$ is a subgroup if $N$ of the same cardinality as $N.$ Could it be that $HN$ and $N$ are distinct?

Comment: We are given that $\gcd(|H|, [G : N]) = 1,$ so this quite naturally suggests that we should use Lagrange’s Theorem.

Comment: After revisiting this. There are so many unclear things. How did you get the order of HN? Lagrange's theorem simply states that the order of any subgroup of G divides the order of G. How do the equalities follow from such a simple statement?

Comment: Ultimately, it's just a matter of showing that there are $|H| / |H \cap N|$ distinct left cosets of $N$ in $HN.$ One can achieve this by showing that the distinct left cosets of $N$ in $HN$ are in bijection with the distinct left cosets of $H \cap N$ in $H;$ then, use Lagrange's Theorem to count the latter. Once you have this, then use the fact that each left coset of $N$ in $HN$ has cardinality $|N|$ to finish up.

Answer (score 1):

$(|H|,|G:N|)=1$, so there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$m|G:N|+n|H|=1.$$

Next we only need to verify that $H\subset N$.
For every $h\in H$,
\begin{align*}
    hN & =h^{m|G:N|+n|H|}N \\
       & =h^{m|G:N|}N \\
       & =(hN)^{m|G:N|} \\
       & =N,
\end{align*}
which means that $h\in N$, therefore $H\subset N$.