# What does $\gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ where $H,K \le G$ imply for the structure of a group G? What about $\gcd(|H|,|G:N|)=1$ where N is normal in G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to better understand what it means for two subgroups to have $\gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$, where $H,K \le G$ Specifically, what does it tell us about the structure of the group G?

Does normality of one of the subgroups H or K to G, change anything?

Sorry if this question is too broad.I'm just trying to get a better understanding of this since I'm struggling with proofs where this comes up(it tends to show up in isomorphism proofs).

For an example where this shows up and i have no idea why it behaves the way it behaves, see:
[Let $G$ be a finite group, $H\le G$ and $N\unlhd G$ such that $\gcd(|H|,[G:N])=1$. Prove that $H\le N$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729469/let-g-be-a-finite-group-h-le-g-and-n-unlhd-g-such-that-gcdh-gn-1)

Comment: In your example the condition we have isn't that the gcd of the subgroups is $1$, it's that the gcd of $|H|$ and $[G : N]$ is $1$. This is a different condition! So which one are you asking about?

Comment: Both. I'm just asking for help in understanding the behavior of groups under these types of conditions.

Comment: The basic facts to use are things like the isomorphism theorems and Lagrange's theorem. In your example, quotienting by $N$ gives a quotient map $f : G \to G/N$ and we can restrict this map to $H$ to get a map $H \to G/N$. The image of this map must have order dividing $|H|$ but also must have order dividing $|G/N|$, and by hypothesis these are coprime, so the order is $1$. So every element of $H$ lies in the kernel of $f$, which by construction is $N$. Which step is unclear?

Comment: I understand what you said. However, in the example, how does this imply that $H \le N$?

Comment: "So every element of $H$ lies in the kernel of $f$, which by construction is $N$."

Comment: Ah, thank you. Sorry about that. I understand your explanation. These questions seem so simple once you see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer to the stated question, if $\gcd(|H|, |K|) = 1$ then using the same Lagrange's theorem argument as in the comments we can conclude that no conjugate of $H$ nontrivially intersects a conjugate of $K$. This implies, for example, that $H$ acts freely on the cosets $G/K$ and vice versa. It also implies that if $K$ is normal, then $H$ embeds into the quotient $G/K$, and vice versa. A nice family of examples where $\gcd(|H|, |K|) = 1$ occurs is if $H$ and $K$ are [Sylow subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) with respect to different primes.