# There is no proper subgroup in $G$ other than $H$ with index less than $n.$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order $N$, where $N > (n − 1)!$ for some positive integer $n > 2$.
> Suppose that $G$ has a composition series $1 \triangleleft H  \triangleleft G$ with $G/H \cong \mathbb Z_p$, where $p < n$ is a prime number, and that any nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ intersects with $H$ nontrivially.
> Show that there is no proper subgroup in $G$ other than $H$ with index less than $n$.

Suppose that there exists $P<G$ with index $m = |G:P|<n$. We may act with $G$ on the set of left cosets $G/P$ by induced multiplication. Then, the kernel of this action $K = \bigcap_{g\in G} gPg^{-1}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $K\leq P$ and $|G/K| \mid m!$.

One can not have $K=1$, otherwise we would have $(n-1)!<|G|\leq m! \leq (n-1)!,$ since $m\leq n-1$. Thus, by the hypothesis, we have $K\cap H \neq 1$ (I am still unsure how to use this information in order to solve the problem).

Moreover, by this problem  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729469/let-g-be-a-finite-group-h-le-g-and-n-unlhd-g-such-that-gcdh-gn-1), we must have $P\leq H$. Since $K\leq P$, then $K\leq H$. Therefore, $K\cap H= K$. Hence, from the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem, we know that $H/K = H/(K\cap H) \cong KH/K$. Since $G/H \cong [G/(K\cap H)]/[H/K\cap H] $ by the 3rd Isomorphism Theorem, and since $G/H$ is simple, it follows that the normal group $H/(K\cap H)$ is maximal, i.e., $H/K$ is a maximal normal subgroup of $G/K$.

However, I dunno how to use alll the information collected above to conclude this problem. How to show that $P=H?$

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: $K$ is normal in $G$, so $K\cap H$ is also normal in $G$ (as $H$ is itself normal) and in $H$. But because you have a composition series,  $H$ is simple, so $H\cap K=1$ or $H$. If You've already proven that $K\leq P\leq H$ and $K\neq 1$, this gives you $K=P=H$, which is what you want.